# AVQueuePlayer current item is null after the last item playback is complete

Tags: ios, avqueueplayer

I am using AVQueue Player to enqueue hls streams.
After the last stream has been played, the currentItem seems to be null :

```
NULL==avPlayerInstance.currentItem
```

returns true.

However, I want the last item to stay in the queue player, since I want to allow the user to rewind the last item. How can this be accomplished? 
tried pausing the player when `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` is fired, but seems it is fired after the playback is complete.